# warnings::warn and FATAL categories in Perl

Tags: perl, warnings

I must be understanding the warnings documentation wrong.  The way I read it, this code:

```
use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
warnings::warn('numeric', 'blarg');
print "finished\n";
```

Should print the 'blarg' warning and die since I've asked for all warnings to be fatal.  However, when I run the code I get:

```
$> /opt/local/bin/perl x.pl 
blarg at x.pl line 3
finished
```

Can somone help me understand why I can't get warn to die?

Comment: A warning severe enough to be fatal sound like an *error* to me. This is the difference, warnings *aren't* fatal.

Comment: @pavium: there is a distinction, but the warnings pragma's FATAL option is intended to promote warnings to errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay. This is ugly. I had a post half-prepared explaining this as a bug in `warnings`, and then I realized it's not, it's just a really *evil* subtlety in the way `warnings` works.

Warnings starts looking for a relevant stack frame to get the warning bits from in `warnings::warn`'s *caller's* caller. The idea is that you're writing some module and you use `warnings::warn` or `warnings::warnif` in your functions, and whether or not the warning is printed (or fatal) depends on the `use warnings` setting in scope in *the code that uses your module*. There's no option provided to have it start at `caller(1)` instead of `caller(2)`, so the effect you want isn't possible.

An example of code that does work (and demonstrates how this interface was expected to be used by whoever wrote it):

```
package Foo;
require warnings;

sub bail {
  warnings::warnif('numeric', "You fool! You divided by zero!");
}

package main;
use warnings FATAL => all;

Foo::bail();
print "Will never be reached\n";
```

And you can't defeat the way it works by just adding another level of subroutines, because it takes the flags from the first caller that's in a *different package* from the caller of `warn`/`warnif`/`enable`/etc.

Comment: You could wrap it in a pointless sub. `sub bail{ use warnings FATAL => all; sub{warnings::warn('DANGER')}->() }`

Comment: @hobbs: you've got it.  the subs in the warnings package are intended for module developers, not as some kind of super warn().

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a (evil subtlety you say) feature <g>. Thanks for the explanation.